# The meaning of "His eyes were hollow-set."

Tags: meaning

> 'I heard the bells jingle at the back of the stand, and a red leg
>   waved over it; then a black one. So, very slowly, Rahere the King's
>   jester straddled the edge of the planks, and looked down on us,
>   rubbing his chin. **Loose-knit**, with cropped hair, and a sad
>   priest's face, under his cockscomb cap, that he could twist like a
>   strip of wet leather. **His eyes were hollow-set.**

This is from "Simple Simon" in "Rewards and Fairies" by Kipling.

http://www.telelib.com/authors/K/KiplingRudyard/prose/RewardsFaries/treejustice.html

I do not understand the meaning of below.

Loose-knit,

What does "loose-knit" mean here?

and

His eyes were hollow-set.

I am so glad if somebody kindly teach me.

Answer (score 1):

It means the same as "deep-set" or "deep-socketed" when referring to eyes. Usually it refers to eyes that are set deeply (in hollows) into the skull.

Asians are unlikely to have deep-set eyes because the epicanthic fold effectively fills in the overhang of the ocular orbit.

Also, "loose-knit" means not bound tightly together. For example, a loose-knit group of people would be a group that does not have many strong ties holding them together. Contrast that with, say, a family or clan that is bound together by blood ties.

Comment: Thank you  so much for your answer. I understand so well.

Comment: @HiroshiInagaki: If this answer satisfies your question, you might consider accepting it by clicking the checkmark.